# GWT: finalize object and remove its event handlers

Tags: java, events, gwt, event-handling

In GWT I have class `MyClass` that registers some event handlers. There is an object (`object1`) of `MyClass` that, at a specific moment, I want to finalize and make its handlers stop listening, because after that I am going to create a different `MyClass` object (`object2`).

How can I do that? I already tried with `object1 = null`, but its handerls keep listening (at least for a while).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The handlers might still exist because the gc didn't get around destroying them.
If it is important that the listeners don't continue to exist then they need to be deregistered.

One way to do this is by deregistering the HandlerRegistration. For example a [addClickHandler](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FocusWidget.html#addClickHandler%28com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickHandler%29) returns a [HandlerRegistration](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/shared/HandlerRegistration.html) which can be deregistered. When and how to do this depends on your GUI classes. You could put the deregistration in your finalize method but you will probably find that these methods are called very sporadically because of the gc and of course because this is not java but javaScript. So concider putting them in a detach or destroy method of your gui element [onDetach](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Widget.html#onDetach%28%29) or [onUnload](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Widget.html#onUnload%28%29).

Comment: In fact, `finalize()` method is never called in GWT, because it doesn't exists in JavaScript, so it can't be emulated.